# Xamarin iOS: how to bind an extensions property?

Tags: c#, xamarin, properties, xamarin.ios

I am starting to use the GitHub's [SDAutoLayout library](https://github.com/gsdios/SDAutoLayout) in my xamarin.ios project.
This library has lots of extensions method and properties of this UIView class.

I built the binding project very easy.
But when I use this lib in my project, I found that all the extensions properties are of no use in the C# application.

And then, if I change the `Sd_layout`'s 'get' property to method --> `SDAutoLayoutModel Sd_layout ();`, the runtime will throw the exception:

> unrecognized selector sent to class
>    [Category]
>       [BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
>       interface UIView_SDAutoLayout
>       {
>           // -(SDAutoLayoutModel *)sd_layout;
>           [Static]
>           [Export("sd_layout")]
>           SDAutoLayoutModel Sd_layout { get; }
>      ..........

So how should I change the extension property in my binding project and use it as the extension method in my `xamarin.ios` project`

Comment: I (hopefully) improved the formatting of the question by highlighting some keywords and emphasizing the error message.

Comment: The original issue with properties can be seen here: https://github.com/xamarin/ObjectiveSharpie/issues/96

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the property/method is `[Static]` and on a `[Category]`. The binding generator tries to either use an extension method (which requires a instance) or to extend the type (which it can't do since it is a UIKit type).

### Non-UIKit Base Types

The simplest solution is to force the generator to just do as much as it can, and then you can help out. There might be a better way, but this works.

First, move all the `[Static]` members into a new type (if they all are static, then skip this one). It might be good to use a user-friendly name as they will actually be typing this one out. In you case, you could use `SDAutoLayoutUIView` or something.

Then, remove the `[Category]` attribute, add the `[Static]` attribute to the **class**, and make sure the `[BaseType]` attribute is there.

This will now create a compiler error about `class_ptr` not existing. This is because the category is expecting the generator to do something, but for some reason it doesn't... (sounds like a bug.)

Anyway, just create a tiny class as an additional file, with a single member:

```
private static readonly IntPtr class_ptr = Class.GetHandle("UIView");
```

Now, everything should work. The final code is this in the `Additions.cs`:

```
partial class SDAutoLayoutUIView
{
    private static readonly IntPtr class_ptr = Class.GetHandle("UIView");
}
```

And your binding code should be this:

```
// ...

[Category]
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
interface UIView_SDAutoLayout
{
    // ... instance methods
}

[Static]
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
interface SDAutoLayoutUIView
{
    // ... static methods

    // -(SDAutoLayoutModel *)sd_layout;
    [Static]
    [Export("sd_layout")]
    SDAutoLayoutModel Sd_layout ();
}

// ...
```

This should do it. This option is great as we just have to do one line for a whole set of methods. If there is only one or two, this is not really that big of an advantage, but still is less work.

### UIKit Base Types

This above works fine, if the object does not inherit from `UIView`. This is because the generator does extra for UIKit classes to get the appearance bit bound too.

If this is the case, you will have to keep the generated binding, but make it `[Internal]`. Here is some more info:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/1862

So, your binding code should be like this (original with new `[Internal]`):

```
[Category]
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
interface UIView_SDAutoLayout
{
    // -(SDAutoLayoutModel *)sd_layout;
    [Static]
    [Internal]
    [Export("sd_layout")]
    SDAutoLayoutModel Sd_layout();
}
```

But, your additions code then does it properly:

```
partial class UIView_SDAutoLayout
{
    public static SDAutoLayoutModel Sd_layout()
    {
        // use the extension method
        return (null as UIView).Sd_layout();
    }
}
```

This works as we are hiding the weird extension method from the user, and wrapping it up as a nice static method that doesn't need some null value. Effectively, this is a limitation of the tools as it always uses an extension method for categories, but static methods can't be extensions in C#.

Note: you may want to use a nice name for the class: `SDAutoLayoutUIView`

This is great if the base type is a UIKit type, such as UIView. (This also works with any type, and is not limited to UIKit types.) But, it does require marking all the static methods as internal, and then creating the correct overload for each. Not a problem if you need them, and there are usually not that many to do.

### Owned Base Types

The best and easiest case is when you own the base type. For example if this was your binding:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
interface MyThing
{
}

[Category]
[BaseType(typeof(MyThing))]
interface Others_MyThing
{
    [Static]
    [Export("createNewThing")]
    MyThing CreateNewThing ();
}
```

In this instance, just simply move the member into the non-category type:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UIView))]
interface MyThing
{
    [Static]
    [Export("createNewThing")]
    MyThing CreateNewThing ();
}

[Category]
[BaseType(typeof(MyThing))]
interface Others_MyThing
{
}
```

Comment: ah hi,I follow your step to do.And it cannot be compile successed.error message is 'SDAutoLayoutUIView': static classes cannot be used as constraints.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the appearance classes generated if the type inherits from UIView. Let me edit my post...

Comment: Hello,@Matthew,I flow your new internal keyword  to do this,and it's compile successfully.But,It's not a extension method for me .Just a class's static method.And do you clear my case is that I must use the IOS's extension property `-(SDAutoLayoutModel *)sd_layout;` as the extension method in my c# solution

Comment: [This SDAutolayout library in GitHub I want to use in my xamarin.ios project](https://github.com/gsdios/SDAutoLayout).In the project's demo's seconde page sample.It teaching me how to use the sd_layout ios'property in the xcode project.So this the difficult for me in the xamarin binding project

Comment: That is correct. You cannot use it as an extension method because it isn't. But, if you use the status method and pass the view as the **parameter**, it comes to the same thing: `SDAutoLayoutUIView.Sd_layout(_centerButton).CenterXEqualToView(...`

Comment: Well,awesome method of calling,I See,But no parameter define at this function`public static SDAutoLayoutModel Sd_layout()`,So I put the _centerButton object to the static function.VisualStudio didn't complile it for me:No overload for method 'Sd_layout' takes 1 arguments

Comment: You are right again... but I am looking at the obj-c code and that method is **not** static. I ran sharpie, and it dod not add the `[Static]` attribute - did you add it to your original binding? To fix all this, go right mack to your original binding and just remove the `[Static]` attribute.

Comment: I ran it, and this is my output: https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/f72ca5be7bc3a3f2ee9b6a8d40566943

Comment: I did a bit more changes, and specifically your method: https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/2195b3ca97982f5c03717910786a9563#file-partial-binding-cs-L265-L272

Comment: I notice that there are a few `{get;set;}` properties on the category. All of these need to be changed to two methods (until the tooling catches up). Here are some tips/docs: https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/2048e1f8de9acb32af311921baacbe4c

Comment: Hi,My sharpie is up to date.You are right that I add `Static` attribute to all extension properties.But if I didn't do this.I must remove all `Category` attribute from all class so that Visual Studio will compile successfully.After that, I use the dll in the project.And how associated the sd_autolayout with the `_centerButton` ?

Comment: Hi!!! I think I know what your mean!!!After I chage the get set properties to function. It's compile successfully.But still have a problem:`[Export("sd_closeAutoLayout")]``bool Sd_closeAutoLayout { [Bind("sd_isClosingAutoLayout")] get; set; }` How to change this property.

Comment: You follow the same rules, but use the `[Bind]` value for the getter's export. See here: https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/2048e1f8de9acb32af311921baacbe4c

Comment: Hello @Matthew, you have help me use the third libray in my xamarin.ios project successfully.And you can update you answer post with our comment context ,after that I will choose your post as the true answer : ) .Thanks a lot .